# What's a slow growing, low maintenance water plant?

Tags: plant-recommendations

I'm asking for a home experiment, in which I need a slow-growing(so I don't have to trim it) water plant with leaves above water.

Comment: Do you need an indoor water plant or outdoor?  If outdoors how much light, how much water depth, how cold does it get?

Answer (score 1):

Water lilies are aquatic plants that have leaves that float on the water surface so you wouldn't need to trim any leaves that grow out of the water.

[image: hardy lily]